# Typescript, signalR and date in an object

Tags: javascript, signalr, typescript, signalr-hub

I have a strange problem and am unsure on what exactly is causing it and not sure how to fix it in a clever way.

I have a signalR app that sends an object, which contains a date to my client. My client is written in TypeScript, although i am not sure if this has any influence on this or not.

The date in my object is a local date, not UAT. 
I need to show the date this way, but when the date arrives in my client it get converted.
It is almost as if the client assumes that the date is UAT and then converts it automatically to local time of the client.

i do not want it to be converted. i just want it displayed as it is.
The one solution i can think of is to convert the date on my server side (c#) to a string first and then send it over like that.

Any better ideas? I don't know if it is signalR that is doing it or it's some sort of std JS behavior. I am really a c# developer and this confuses me completely.

Comment: SignalR only converts to and from JSON while sending these objects.

Comment: It would be helpful if you can sniff the SignalR traffic and see what format it sends the date as.  Perhaps it is attaching a "+0" for timezone, or simply sending a Date(number).

Answer (score 0):

i was also stuck in this datetime issue how i solved is to keep my datetime in UTC in server and let the  js handle the conversion and all